# "Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point. (net6.0-android)" on .Net Maui

Tags: android, ios, .net, maui, maui-blazor

when i start running .net maui app on ios I get the error "Error CS0017 Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point. .... (net6.0-android)".

It works on android simulator and android real device.
i am trying to run the application from windowsns on ios simulator.But it's not working.

My .csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>
    <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
    <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Setre.Belatrix</RootNamespace>
    <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
    <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <EnableDefaultCssItems>false</EnableDefaultCssItems>
    <MainEntryPoint>Setre.Belatrix.Program</MainEntryPoint>
    <!-- Display name -->
    <ApplicationTitle>Belatrix</ApplicationTitle>

    <!-- App Identifier -->
    <ApplicationId>com.setre.mobil</ApplicationId>
    <ApplicationIdGuid>0C54D070-A66A-48F5-AA93-8F952C9BA345</ApplicationIdGuid>

    <!-- Versions -->
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>12.1</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>46</ApplicationVersion>

    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">16.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">33.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

    <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\playstore.svg" />
    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\logo.svg" Color="White" BaseSize="256,256" />

    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android'">
    <GoogleServicesJson Include="Platforms\Android\google-services.json" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-ios'">
    <BundleResource Include="Platforms\iOS\GoogleService-Info.plist" Link="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Platforms\Android\Resources\push_sound.wav" />
    <None Remove="Platforms\Android\Resources\values\strings.xml" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Images\take.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Splash\sp.jpg" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Platforms\Android\Resources\push_sound.wav" />
    <Content Include="Resources\push_sound.wav" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui" Version="7.0.0.1-pre" />
    <PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="5.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.7.0-preview-23364-03" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="110.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Build.Download" Version="0.11.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Facebook.CoreKit.iOS" Version="12.2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Facebook.GamingServicesKit.iOS" Version="12.2.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>



<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Pages\Ticket\BasarisizMain.xaml.cs">
        <DependentUpon>BasarisizMain.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>



<ItemGroup>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Account\LoginMain.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Sales\AfterCamera.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Sales\CameraForOrder.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Sales\OrderLineDetailMain.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Sales\OrderProformaMain.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Sales\ProductListMain.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Sales\SalesıIndexMain.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Ticket\BasarisizMain.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Ticket\BekleyenMain.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Ticket\ChatboxMain.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Ticket\DetailMain.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Ticket\IncomingSelection.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Ticket\IncomingTickets.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Ticket\InsertMain.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
    <MauiXaml Update="Pages\Ticket\OutgoingTickets.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </MauiXaml>
</ItemGroup>



<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>***</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass>**</AndroidSigningStorePass>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>*</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass>*</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <CodesignKey>***</CodesignKey>
    <CodesignProvision>belatrixIOSKEY</CodesignProvision>
    <ArchiveOnBuild>true</ArchiveOnBuild>
    <TcpPort>*</TcpPort>
    <ServerAddress>*</ServerAddress>
    <ServerUser>***</ServerUser>
    <ServerPassword>***</ServerPassword>
    <_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory>/Users/setre/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/</_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <UseInterpreter Condition="$(TargetFramework.EndsWith('-ios'))">true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Properties used to strip bitcode from frameworks when using Visual Studio for Mac -->
    <_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterAfterTargets Condition="'$(OS)'=='Unix'">_ExpandNativeReferences</_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterAfterTargets>
    <_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets Condition="'$(OS)'=='Unix'">_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksOnMac</_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets>

    <!-- Properties used to strip bitcode from frameworks when using Visual Studio for Windows -->
    <_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterAfterTargets Condition="'$(OS)'!='Unix'">_ComputeFrameworkFilesToPublish</_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterAfterTargets>
    <_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets Condition="'$(OS)'!='Unix'">_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksOnWindows</_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
    <MtouchUseLlvm>True</MtouchUseLlvm>
    <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-ios|AnyCPU'">
    <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios'">
    <ProvisioningType>automatic</ProvisioningType>
    <CodesignProvision></CodesignProvision>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterTarget" Condition="'$(_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets)'!='' AND @(_FrameworkNativeReference-&gt;Count()) != 0" AfterTargets="$(_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterAfterTargets)" DependsOnTargets="$(_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksMasterDependsOnTargets)" />

<Target Name="_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksOnMac" Condition="('$(OutputType)'!='Library' OR '$(IsAppExtension)'=='True') AND '$(_SdkIsSimulator)'=='False'">

    <!-- Find the bitcode_strip command -->
    <Exec Command="xcrun -find bitcode_strip" ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="_BitcodeStripCommand" />
    </Exec>

    <!-- Strip the bitcode from frameworks -->
    <Exec Command="$(_BitcodeStripCommand) %(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity) -r -o %(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity)" />
</Target>

<Target Name="_StripBitcodeFromFrameworksOnWindows" Condition="('$(OutputType)'!='Library' OR '$(IsAppExtension)'=='True') AND '$(_SdkIsSimulator)'=='False' AND '$(IsMacEnabled)'=='true'">

    <!-- Strip the bitcode from frameworks -->
    <Exec SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" Command="&quot;%24(xcrun -find bitcode_strip)&quot; %(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity) -r -o %(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity)" />

    <CopyFileFromBuildServer SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" File="%(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity)" TargetFile="%(_FrameworkNativeReference.Identity)" />
</Target>
```

[MyProject.Platforms.iOS.Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LdCl.png)

My application was running on iOS before. After the last changes I made, I got an error like this. Even if I undo the changes, the application does not work. I am waiting for the application to run in the ios simulator

Comment: Always keep your .NET version up to date. It is totally useless to ask about 6.0. People are working on 8.0. Portion of that is rolled in 7.0 too. And almost nothing is ported to 6.0. Also, post your question as text, not as image.

Comment: Please provide more context and try to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you get an error about `net6.0-android` while debugging on **iOS**, it usually means that something is misconfigured with regards to multi-targeting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try to pair to the mac and then run it on the mac's ios simulator?